# Загрузка адреса из firebase в mapView

Tags: swift, firebase, map, geocoding, mapview

Пытаюсь выгрузить адрес из firebase и разместить его на mapView. Но почему то адрес не хочет выгружаться. Адрес прописан строкой в firebase типа - **Москва, Улица такая-то, дом 1**.
В чем может быть причина не загрузки данных?

```
var allAddresses: String = ""

addressRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        self.allAddresses = value["address"] as? String ?? ""
    })
```

**Firebase:**

```
{
  «Address» : {
    «AddressOne» : {
      "address" : "Москва, Пресненская набережная д.8, квартира 195, подъезд 94",
    },
    "AddressTwo» : {
      "address" : "Москва, ул. Правды д.24 строение 3",
    },
    "AddressThree» : {
      "address" : "Москва,ул.Электрозаводская д.21",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: У вас очень сумбурный вопрос. Возникает какая-то ошибка? Можете показать этот json на firebase?

Comment: Ошибки нету, может как-то не правильно пишу код при выгрузке из firebase
JSON добавил

Comment: addressRef точно относится к внутреннему адресу?

Comment: print(snapshot) явно не помешает

Comment: Да, точно. Все выводится. Но я уже решил проблему. Спасибо :)